# Unable to get good results when trying to predict mean as well as standard deviation in a image regression task

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to regress two variables (mean and std) and then trying to optimize log(gaussian_distribution) = log(std) + (target - mean) / (2 * std ^ 2).

Note that on the same data, if change loss to (or even just use (target - mean) ^ 2 in my defined function) MSE on the first variable, I am able to get a very good score of the mean.

I am unable to figure out the mistake in the code or figure out a reason why it should not work.

Here is the code

```
 def gaussian_loss(y2, y1):                              
     std = K.exp(y1[:,1])                                                        
     mean = y1[:,0]                                                                                                  
     return K.mean(K.log(std) + K.square(mean - y2[:,0]) / (2 * K.square(std)), axis = -1)
```

I have implemented this in Keras. Some related blogs (https://engineering.taboola.com/predicting-probability-distributions/)

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this loss, your implementation was my first try, and as you say it just does not work. I am not sure why, but here is a correct way to implement this loss:

```
def regression_nll_loss(sigma_sq, epsilon = 1e-6):
    def nll_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return 0.5 * K.mean(K.log(sigma_sq + epsilon) + K.square(y_true - y_pred) / (sigma_sq + epsilon))

    return nll_loss
```

As you see this loss only takes supervised labels for the mean. The variance has to be passed directly to the loss as a tensor:

```
inp = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(10, activation="relu")(inp)
x = Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(30, activation="relu")(x)
mean = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
var = Dense(1, activation="softplus")(x)

train_model = Model(inp, mean)
pred_model = Model(inp, [mean, var])

train_model.compile(loss=regression_nll_loss(var), optimizer="adam")
```

Then you can use `train_model` for training normally with `model.fit`, and `pred_model` to make predictions.

You can see a full example using my library at: https://github.com/mvaldenegro/keras-uncertainty/blob/master/examples/regression_deep-ensemble.py

I think it is also possible to implement this loss using the `add_loss` API, but I have not tried.

Comment: I tried the thing you suggest (I also had a look at your repository). I am getting constant output values irrespective of the input (they have very low variance). I do a pred_model.save() and load the use keras.models.load_model to load the pred model. Is there any other thing that I should take care of or anything else that I can try?